# Combining Polymer and Razor

Tags: razor, polymer

Is there a way to combine Razor (CSHTML) with Polymer elements? Or is it mandatory that a Polymer element should be HTML to be imported?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine any template engine by either:

- Compiling custom templates to produce HTML output
- Using Polymer's built-in event callbacks/creating custom elements to dynamically compile custom template code to HTML at runtime with a client-side compiler

So, generally speaking, using Polymer shouldn't prevent you in finding a way to use your template engine as you have previously with your other client-side applications.